Vectorize function that takes array elements as inputs
I'm frequently running into problems where I run a for-loop and subset an array. Here's an example of the kind of calculation I'm doing.
import numpy as np

def get_betas(x, y):
    # Calculate parts of OLS formula
    xy = x.T @ y
    xx = x.T @ x
    xx_inv = np.linalg.inv(xx)
    
    # Calculate beta
    beta = xx_inv @ xy
    
    return beta

def calc_oos_error(x, y, k):
    errors = []
    
    for t in range(k, len(y)):
        beta = get_betas(x[:t], y[:t])
        error = y[t] - x[t] @ beta
        errors.append(error)
        
    return np.mean(errors), np.std(errors)

x = np.random.normal(size = 1000)
y = 10 * x + np.random.normal(scale = 1e-2, size = len(x))

x = x.reshape(-1, 1)

a, b = calc_oos_error(x, y, 10)

I would like to vectorize out the loop in calc_oos_error. If I try to vectorize the naive way an error is thrown when I run the function.
# Vectorize naive way
calc_oos_error_vec = np.vectorize(calc_oos_error)

# Try to run
calc_oos_error_vec(x = x, y = y, k = np.arange(1, 20))


In this case, the error is

TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len().

In general, the issue is that Python tries to use the elements of the array as inputs instead of using the whole array.
One option would be to use a global reference to x and y.
def calc(t):
    beta = get_betas(x[:t], y[:t])
    error = y[t] - x[t] @ beta
    return error

calc = np.vectorize(calc)    
    
def calc_oos_error_vec(x, y, k):
    errors = calc(np.arange(k, len(y)))
    return np.mean(errors), np.std(errors)

However, this strikes me as confusing and just asking for errors.

an error is thrown. please post the error message as part of the question.

why do you want to use np.vectorize?

@juanpa.arrivillaga Nothing special about that function, except that it's usually a good tool for these sorts of things.

@AhmedAEK Ok. I'll share the error when I try to vectorize calc_oos_error  directly when I get back to the compute with my minimal example. That said, the issue is that using np.vectorize treats the rows of x and y as separate observations instead of one observation that should be applied each time.

YOu aren't answering my question. You say you "would like to vectorize out the loop in calc_oos_error" but np.vectorize, as stated in the documentation, "is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop"

@juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry, I'm just looking to replace the for-loop with something more efficient if possible. My experience has been that np.vectorize has helped speed things up, but I'm open to anything.

@AhmedAEK Error added.

@Charles0349 i couldn't replicate the error, but on the topic of making code faster you want to look into numba or XLA, as those provide both SIMD optimizations and actual thread concurrency.

@AhmedAEK I provided more details about a naive vectorization path that doesn't work. I haven't used numba or XLA before. Perhaps I should use them. But it seems like there should be a way to vectorize this without additional packages, since each iteration isn't dependent on the last.

python is an interpreted language, while producing vectorized code requires JIT compilation, which is why both numba and JAX can do it. if you really must use pure python to speed this up (numpy is not pure python) you can use a threadpool and have each thread run one value of k, but this will only get you like 20-40% speedup at best, just go for the numba path, as it has prange which executes a loop in parallel over multiple cores, which is exactly what you want in this code, the code should be over twice as fast.
